# C# Merge data where value of cell equals another value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would like to be able to get the average of all columns in the following datagridview for each player. For example, In the attached picture the player Terry Rozier is highlighted. I would like to only show 1 record for Terry Rozier but have the average of all of his stats (ex: superstat column 18, salary column 0, fgmadepergame column 4.5,  etc)

[image: sumhelp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out using Linq:

```
       var dupGroups = dt.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Name"))
           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);

        foreach (var group in dupGroups)
        {
            DataRow first = group.First();
            int sum = group.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("SuperStat"))/group.Count();
            first.SetField("SuperStat", sum);
            foreach (DataRow row in group.Skip(1))
                dt.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Recommend to not use the same grid view and merging the result, you can add another grid view to display the selected rows, using the below scenario:

- Get the Selected Rows of first Grid view and put it in a datatable
  (or list)

  foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
      {
      //get the data of selected rows into rows of datatable for example....
      }
- Validate that the selected rows are for the same Player (if
  needed)
- Calculate the Average of columns that you want
- Set the data source of the Second Gridview and bind it

Comment: Couldnt we do something similar to this: 

  for (int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);

But instead of removing merge any column that has a count greater then 1?